# Auto-reload powershell modules on changes or even recognize them recursively

Tags: powershell

Came back to powershell after many years, and trying to implement powershell modules. Was working with Ruby/Python for the past several years, and it feels "weird" trying to import powershell modules. Maybe I am still not understanding them properly? Here for help

TL;DR - here for two issues

1. Having to parse the directory and load the modules individually each time
2. Changes made in cmdlets/functions are in effect only if I run extra steps - open new terminal or `Remove-Module` then `Install-Module` again and again

---

Long story:
This is my directory structure

```
MyModules
  - firstModule
    - firstModule.psm1 => function Run-Something1() {}
    - firstModule.psd1
  - secondModule
    - secondModule.psm1 => function Run-Something2() {}
    - secondModule.psd1
  - etc.
```

Then I've added `MyModules` to `$ENV:PSModulePath`. When I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, I see all the modules under `MyModules` section. Looks like powershell "knows" about my custom modules, but somehow I cannot seem to run them. I get the following error -

```
The term 'Run-Something' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

This is part of my `*.psd1` files, think empty means it exports everything?

```
FunctionsToExport = @()
CmdletsToExport = @()
```

I am currently looping thru `MyModules` directory, and wrote a custom script to invoke `Import-Module` on each `*.psm1` file - so I have these functions/cmdlets recognized in the powershell terminal. Feel like there has to be a better way? Came across Plaster, but not sure if that's a standard way to create new Powershell projects/structure? Also if I am looping thru and running `Import-Module *.psm1` on all available modules myself, what's the point in adding my modules dir to `$ENV:PSModulePath`?

Another "weird" thing I am noticing - my changes in the scripts are not immediately available in the terminal if I rerun the same function. I have kill/re-open the terminal each time for every small change I am making in the `*.psm1` files. Found two possible solutions

1. Use this setting in `"powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true,` but there has to be a better way?
2. `Import-Module *.psm1 -Force` or `Remove-Module *.psm1` and then `Import-Module`

Feel like there might be a better way? Usually this is not an issue at all in Ruby/Python. I kill the process => relaunch the script in the same terminal, and I can see my updated changes in functions/classes in new debug session.

Looking for advice. TIA

Comment: `FunctionsToExport = @()` means the opposite. Export nothing.

Comment: ahh i misread it earlier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.3. read it carefully again, you are right. I changed it back to "*" and can run my functions in terminal now. Thanks. do you know how to auto reload changes into the same terminal session?

Comment: Assuming you're not dealing with binary cmdlets then `Import-Module -Force` will reload everything

Comment: Yes, just regular cmdlets. Do you know if there's a better way other than running `Import-Module` again and again? Think it has something to do with powershell architecture - they seems to cache these modules in the terminal session as I understood it. Looking for instant detection without having to go thru extra steps

Comment: Instead of doing Remove-Module/Import-Module / restarting session what you can do is just force it

Import-Module .\ModuleName.psm1 -Force

BUT if you have classes in your code then that might not work unfortunately - afaik it loads it and then just does not change it until you restart the session

Comment: yea seems there's no "smooth" way in powershell. it's not an issue in other programming languages (ruby/python, etc.)